# Про отладку стилей

Tags: css, отладка

Всем привет,
При отладке стилей, я часто в описание классов добавляю в бордюр значение больше нуля и цвет - чтобы видеть границы этого класса.
И таких классов у меня не один...
По завершении отладки, я этот бордюр ставлю в ноль и он не виден.
Когда нужно отлаживать снова - опять устанавливаю бордюр больше нуля.

Задумался, а можно ли устанавливать этот ключ отладки в одном месте?
Если бы это был php или twig файлы - то сделать по ключу в урле было бы просто - но css  о параметрах ничего не знает...
Или можно что-то придумать?

2) Нет ли каких тулзов для Chrome, Firefox  которые бы умели каким-то образом схематично показывать
все теги(или все стили) по месту их отображение ? Похоже умеет делать инспектор Chrome, но для одного выделенного элемента...

Спасибо !

Comment: Возможно, вы найдете полезным плагин [Tilt 3D](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/tilt/)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй [scss](http://sass-scss.ru), там можно использовать переменные и с помощью них контролировать толщину рамки. Для отладки проверь чтобы были включены sourcemaps

```
$test_border: 1px solid red;

.some_class1 {
   border: $test_border

}

.some_class2 {
   border: $test_border
}
```

Comment: Спасибо
скачал и установил sass-3.4.22
А можно ссылочку на хорошую доку для начала ?
Тут http://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sintaksis/ формальное описание
На харабре статей много, Например https://habrahabr.ru/post/140612/ но она 2012  года - не уверен в ее актуальности для sass-3.4.22 ...